# 2013 - "An unrecognized HTTP response" error in Search Crawling after I reset index

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I get a search problem in my dev Sharepoint 2013 Server that is restored data from UAT server by SPSite-Restore command.
Everything work well until I perform Reset Index process in Sharepoint Search Service Application of Central Admin. After that, I can not run full crawling successfully. This is the error in craw log:

```
An unrecognized HTTP response was received when attempting to crawl this item. Verify whether the item can be accessed using your browser.( SearchID = 6CF057CA-9EFB-4C23-BE6B-AFD7246C3646 )
```

Also, this is the message in log file by the above SearchID:

```
05/25/2015 16:36:05.67     mssdmn.exe (0x0974)       0x2620    SharePoint Server Search        Connectors:HTTP                 du4s    Medium      CHttpAccessorHelper::InitRequestInternal - Request/Response succeeded CorrelationID aac9099d-f6a3-30a6-fc7b-3bcb6c6322c0 URL http://my homepage url SearchRequestTime 3047, SPRequestDuration 0, SPIISLatency 3028, dwStatusCode 302, hr 0x40dca  [httpacchelper.cxx:586]  search\native\gather\protocols\http\httpacchelper.cxx    6cf057ca-9efb-4c23-be6b-afd7246c3646
05/25/2015 16:36:05.67     mssdmn.exe (0x0974)       0x2620    SharePoint Server Search        Connectors:HTTP                  aj4ci   High        CHttpAccessorHelper::InitRequestInternal - tenth redirect or redirect to the same url failing the document http://my homepage url  [httpacchelper.cxx:660]  search\native\gather\protocols\http\httpacchelper.cxx   6cf057ca-9efb-4c23-be6b-afd7246c3646
```

I've searched many times in Internet and tried various solutions: proxy, loopback, create new Search Service Application, extend new web application,...

Please help me make the Sharepoint Search can crawl index as before index reseting with out create new web application. Thanks so much.

More information, The Search can crawl data after index resetting unless I restored data from UAT server - default Sharepoint web application.

Comment: Did you tried restarting search service?

Comment: Thank @Amit, I've tried restarting the Sharepoint Server Search 15. This problem still happens.